# Trying to use PAT for Github authentication

Tags: git, macos

I added my PAT to my Mac's Keychain Access for Github...

I also updated the origin's URL to use the token... I still get the below error message.

Is there some step I'm missing? Should I just do SSH authentication(tried this but git said my key wasn't valid)?

````
remote: Permission to username/bd0823.git denied to username.
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/username/bd0823/': The requested URL returned error: 403 ```
````

Answer (score 3):

HTTP 403 indicates that you're providing correct credentials (username and PAT), but that those credentials are unauthorized to perform whatever action you've requested. I can't tell exactly where the problem is, as you provided very very little detail, but it could be one or more of the following:

1. PAT was created without proper permissions
2. Username doesn't have write permission on that repo
3. You're attempting to push to a protected branch, and you don't have permission to do that